# Javascript. Give value to variable depending on parameter value

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, conditional-statements

I have been given a Javascript code, and there is a sentence I cannot fully understand:

```
var isFaculty = (paramArray[0] == "yes"),
```

isFaculty variable is used afterthat in a equation, where more variables are involved. While the latter are defined along the code, the former is supposed to be defined (i.e. numerical value) by that sentence, as it depends on a parameterArray that the user should introduce (the parameter array is of size 3, anyway). For cell [0], paramArray can have two values, namely "yes" or "no".

I am wondering a possibility, but any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance,

/Jorge.

Comment: When you say  "any help is welcome", what help specifically do you need? To understand the line of code you have provided?

Comment: It just sets `isFaculty` to true or false depending on the value of `paramArray[0]`

Comment: help yourself understand `console.log(paramArray[0] == "yes")`. Also look up what `==` operator does

Comment: I wanted to understand if isFaculty gets any specific numerical value (0,1) depending if the parameter value is no or yes, respectively

Answer (score 1):

```
(paramArray[0] == "yes")
```

This is like a mini `if` statement that returns either `true or false`.
`isFaculty` is a boolean variable that captures that result.
Once the `true or false` is caught it can be used as a numeric `1 or 0` that even though is not recommended but could be multiplied by a number to turn it into a `0` if it's `false` or leave it unchanged if it's `true`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. The point is that isFaculty variable is involved in a formula as follows:

var xExample = 1/(1+Math.exp(-(-2 + 4*city - 0.11*gender + 0.6*isFaculty + 0.2*city*gender - 0.424885*city*isFaculty - 0.3*city*gender*isFaculty)));

consequently, I understand that isFaculty gets value 1 or 0 depending on being true or false?

Answer (score 0):

== is a comparator that will return a boolean value, so the code you have will assign `true` or `false` to `isFaculty`
The var name isXxxx would suggest to me that its value would be boolean.

So what you have is basically:

```
var isFaculty  - for the variable isFaculty
=              - assign the value of the following expression
paramArray[0]  - take the first value from the array paramArray
==             - check if it matches in content but not necessarily type with
"yes"          - the string value that you are looking for to assign true
```

Implicitly this also means that if the content of paramArray[0] does not match with the content of the string value "yes" then the value of isFaculty will be false.

This could be used as a 'flag' later on by using false as 0 and true as 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand it, but then I cannot understand how it translates into the formula I posted below. Just 0/1?

Comment: Yes, the value of that variable can only be true or false, which can only be used numerically as 1 or 0.